# WPF ListView Databound Drag/Drop Auto Scroll

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, collections, drag-and-drop

I've been working with Bea's solution [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53) for a while and finding it very helpful.  Problem now I'm having is when I drag-n-drop items within or to another ListView control and I want to scroll up/down "during" the drag (moving an item from index 30 to index 1), it's not happening.  I would have to drag to the top of the visual items in the ListView, manually scroll up, then drag again, eventually ending at the position I want.  This isn't very user friendly.

Now I found the function (DragDropHelper.DropTarget_PreviewDragOver) that I would want to do the testing of which item is being dragged over, and I'm getting that.

```
Dim pt As Point = e.GetPosition(DirectCast(Me.targetItemsControl, UIElement))

' Perform the hit test against a given portion of the visual object tree.
Dim result As HitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Me.targetItemsControl, pt)
```

Now from there I can get the DependencyProperty of this visual hit

```
Dim lvi As ListViewItem = TryCast(GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(TryCast(result.VisualHit, DependencyObject), GetType(ListViewItem)), ListViewItem)
```

Which is of a ListViewItem.  Now in the function DropTarget_PreviewDragOver I have the "DraggedItem" which is of type Picture in Bea's example, but that can change depending on the ObservableCollection you have bound to the ListView.  Now, I want to drag the ListView up or down depending on where the mouse is on the control.  I've attempted with the below un-finished non-working code

```
If lvi IsNot Nothing Then
    If pt.Y <= 25 Then
        Dim lv As ListView = TryCast(targetItemsControl, ListView)
        If lv IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim index As Integer = lv.Items.IndexOf(lvi)
            If index > 1 Then
                lv.ScrollIntoView(lv.Items(index - 1))
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If pt.Y >= Me.targetItemsControl.ActualHeight - 25 Then
            Debug.Print("Scroll Down")
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this ItemsControl or ListView to scroll when dragging over the items??

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I still haven't had time to look into this any more.  Have you ran across something since you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still messing around with this exact same issue too.  I'm using a slightly modified version of Bea's Drag and Drop found [here](http://hinshlabs.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=31504), which is in VB instead of C#.  When I used ScrollIntoView as described above, I could scroll down but not up.  So I messed around and came up with this as my DropTarget_PreviewDragOver:

```
 Private Sub DropTarget_PreviewDragOver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)
        Dim draggedItem As Object = e.Data.GetData(Me.m_format.Name)
        Me.DecideDropTarget(e)
        If (Not draggedItem Is Nothing) Then
            If (TypeOf m_targetItemsControl Is ListBox) Then
                Dim lb As ListBox = CType(m_targetItemsControl, ListBox)
                Dim temp As Integer = m_insertionIndex
                Dim scroll As ScrollViewer = Utilities.GetScrollViewer(lb)
                If scroll.VerticalOffset = temp Then
                    temp -= 1
                End If
                If temp >= 0 And temp <= (lb.Items.Count - 1) Then
                    lb.ScrollIntoView(lb.Items(temp))
                End If
            End If
            Me.ShowDraggedAdorner(e.GetPosition(Me.m_topWindow))
            Me.UpdateInsertionAdornerPosition()
        End If
        e.Handled = True
    End Sub
```

and I had to include this utility function, taken from [here](http://www.developingfor.net/wpf/fun-with-the-wpf-scrollviewer.html)

```
    Public Shared Function GetScrollViewer(ByVal listBox As ListBox)
    Dim scroll_border As Decorator = CType(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listBox, 0), Decorator)
    If (TypeOf scroll_border Is Decorator) Then
        Dim scroll As ScrollViewer = CType(scroll_border.Child, ScrollViewer)
        If (TypeOf scroll Is ScrollViewer) Then
            Return scroll
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If


End Function
```

which is great and all.  Then running out what theuberk mentioned above with the adorner moving, and in the spirit of making this easy for someone else later, I added a variable to the DragDropAdorner class:

```
    Private m_mouseDelta As Point
```

Added this to the last line of DragSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown:

```
        Me.m_mouseDelta = e.GetPosition(m_sourceItemContainer)
```

And turned ShowDraggedAdorner into:

```
    Private Sub ShowDraggedAdorner(ByVal currentPosition As Point)
    If (Me.m_draggedAdorner Is Nothing) Then
        Dim adornerLayer As AdornerLayer = adornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(Me.m_topWindow.Content)
        Me.m_draggedAdorner = New DraggedAdorner(Me.m_draggedData, DragDropBehavior.GetDragTemplate(Me.m_sourceItemsControl), m_topWindow.Content, adornerLayer)
    End If
    Me.m_draggedAdorner.SetPosition((currentPosition.X - m_mouseDelta.X), (currentPosition.Y - m_mouseDelta.Y))
    End Sub
```

Comment: I finally got to implementing this and testing it really quick. Looks great!  Worked just fine!  Thanks!

Comment: I did find one problem though, I was using double clicking on the list box as an alternative to dragging items between two controls.  Using the method like above it was having problems detecting a single click between a double click and the source list would have the item added back what I just removed.  So in the mouse down function I added "If e.Clicks = 1 Then Do Drag Else Set DraggedData = Nothing", that should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was took advantage of the `ListBox.ScrollIntoView` method. Basically, when you update your drop target, you can just call this method on it and wpf will do all the work. All you need to know is the index of the drop target item. This handles both vertical and horizontal scrolling.

`this.listView.ScrollIntoView(this.listView.Items[index]);`

When you use this method, your adorner might move with the scrolling ListBox. To fix this, I just set my adorner parent and adorner layer parent to the content of the window at the top of the visual tree (i.e. `topWindow.Content`).

Comment: I'll give this a try, thanks for posting 3 months later :) I thought it was forgotten about..

Comment: thanks! I did it similar

lstMessages.ScrollIntoView(lstMessages.Items[lstMessages.Items.Count-1]);

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to scroll is to use the ScrollBar-Commands. You can do this without climbing down the VisualTree. If you have a styles ListBox with no border the GetScrollViewer()-Method would not work anymore.

I use the first Element of the ItemContainerGenerator as CommandTarget for the ScrollBar.LineXXXCommand:

```
Point p = e.GetPosition(itemsControl);
  IInputElement commandTarget = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as IInputElement;

  if (commandTarget != null)
  {
    if (p.Y < OFFSET_TO_SCROLL)
      ScrollBar.LineUpCommand.Execute(null, commandTarget);
    else if (p.Y > itemsControl.ActualHeight - OFFSET_TO_SCROLL)
      ScrollBar.LineDownCommand.Execute(null, commandTarget);

    if (p.X < OFFSET_TO_SCROLL)
      ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand.Execute(null, commandTarget);
    else if (p.X > itemsControl.ActualWidth - OFFSET_TO_SCROLL)
      ScrollBar.LineRightCommand.Execute(null, commandTarget);
  }
```

Calling the LineXXXCommands is similiar to clicking the Arrow-Buttons of a ScrollBar: The ScrollViewer scrolles by a certain ammount which you can configure by setting the 'SmallAmount' Property of the ScrollBar.