# In WPF how do I distinguish a mouse hit in a list box item or the scroll bar

Tags: c#, wpf, hittest

I have a WPF list box that contains many items so a scroll bar is shown. I want to add even handler for the user hitting the items but not the scroll bar. How can I do this?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733581/scrolling-while-dragging-and-dropping-wpf I ran into this with drag and drop; can't find the answer I used atm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ItemContainerStyle` to set a handler for the click event on the items using `EventSetter`

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="myHandler"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

An `ItemTemplate` can be added to a `ListBox`. Any WPF Controls you add in this can have various event handlers added to them, including mouse clicks and drags

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label MouseLeftButtonDown="<new event handler>" Content="My Clickable Item"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[Source](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/)